# Windows 8 Xbox Music Support Podcasts?

Tags: windows-8, podcasts, xbox-music

Does anyone know if the new Xbox Music app on Windows 8 (that is supposed to replace the Zune software) support podcast subscriptions and downloads?

Comment: I don't think it's supposed to replace Zune. It doesn't see my Windows Phone at all.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! When you get the answer you're looking for, be sure to accept it and give it an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not support podcast subscriptions yet, but it does support automatically watching folders. This means that you can use another app to download podcasts and listen to them in the Music app.

First app that came up searching for podcast: [SlapDash Podcast](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/app/0c62e66a-f2e4-4403-af88-3430a821741e).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Interesting that, that was left out.

Comment: The Metro apps seem to prefer ease of use over functionality. Maybe it will help them appeal to a wider audience, but it doesn't help the heavy tech users like you and me!

Answer (score 0):

No; I don't see any podcast options..

There are some podcast apps in the Windows Store.